# Jira bugs filtration based on Epic and story links

Tags: jira, jql

I want to filter my jira bugs based on  -
all my issues are linked in stories and
all stories are linked to Epic.
Can I filer bugs from epics based on this relation -
Bug>Story>Epic

I want to apply filer for any epic and want to see the issues under this however I dont have a direct linking with epics.

I tried using JQL quesries but not able to make correct one